# Materials defined by a texture

Tags: materials, node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine, shaders

I have an Earth object where the surface would be with a Bump map and the ocean without it. However, the bump texture is for both and I want to block the parts for the ocean using a black and white texture. It would look something like this - 
[image]

This is easily accomplished in the Cycles render engine by just plugging the texture into the Factor input of the Mix Shader – 
[image]
[image]

How is it done in the Internal render engine?

I tried the same in the internal render engine, but there are some issues. here is the blend file -  http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31825

Comment: Using material nodes. This tutorial is a good example, matching your use-case exactly: http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/create-a-realistic-earth/

Comment: @Gandalf3 Thanks. That's where my Earth is from, but he has the Bump map on both - surface and ocean. I even tried by mixing two materials (one without the map) and then a material with a black and white texture in the Fac, but no results. What would be a good approach?

Comment: Use the color output of the bw texture, not the value output. Somewhat like [this](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/77799).

Comment: @user2859 Thanks. I didn't know how to apply the texture in the node, but there's still something missing. Here's the blend file if that's the case - http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31825

Comment: Hmm.. Works for me, when I add a texture (earth.png isn't packed in the file).

Comment: @user2859 How do you put a texture in the "Texture" node? When I click on the name, there's only "Tax" and that is non specified texture.

Comment: It's better to append the texture to a material that is resident in a material slot (not as a node), otherwise it's a lot harder to edit the texture (e.g. doesn't show up in texture paint mode with multitexture enabled, resets the image source in the uv-editor). Not sure it's intentional though.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. I'm not much of a standard materials user so I'll play around and see if something works.